# Change the window area in Windows

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an application (chat) that I am developing for our company (special requirements).  We are mostly using WinXP computers.  I want it to be topmost and docked to the right, the problem is, I don't want it to overlap other windows that people are working on.

Is there a way to change the default area that other programs can maximize to?  Basically, I want it to look something like this:

[image: Example]

Is something like this possible?  I'm using VB.net so all .net answers are accepted.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible in XP. You're basically asking how to have your application notify Windows that this area cannot be used for other apps, or have your app resize other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following codeproject article:

[Application Desktop Toolbars](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx)

It seems to do what you require.

> This article is about Application Desktop Toolbars, which are
>   applications that can align to the screen much like the taskbar. The
>   article will develop a base class for developing such apps.