# Lock area of work with top always application

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that I can already show on top of any other application using:

```
TopMost = True
```

but it doesn't have the reach I want; since when another maximized application is opened; This new application overlaps behind my application..

Is there any way to block the work area or manipulate the area destined to the maximized applications on the main screen?

I leave an example image, since I have not found any property of the form related to what I want:
[image]

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, ignore it if your read it. Maybe resizing other application windows might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443502/how-do-i-change-another-programs-windows-size

Comment: it can help but what if that external application runs with administrator privileges; I can still move it with my application ???, I really don't want my application to interact directly with others; I want other applications to respect an area of the screen assigned to be viewed in maximized mode. Is it possible to do this??

Comment: @crimson589I think i need something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50662700/7292370

Comment: [Using Application Desktop Toolbars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/application-desktop-toolbars) -- [How do you do AppBar docking (to screen edge, like WinAmp)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84987/7444103). It's setup to work with a WPF Window instead of a Form, but the only difference are the few Properties used to set the Window: a Form has almost the same properties, just slightly different names. The `BeginInvoke()` call is also slightly different, but it works the same in WinForms, you just need to adapt the syntax.

Comment: You can use Application Desktop Toolbars to solve your problems. It makes applications align to the screen much like the taskbar. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449547/change-the-window-area-in-windows?rq=1)